Find out dependedncy modules needed by a specific module in a multi-module Maven project
I have a multi module maven project
Relevant part of the parent pom.xml:
<modules>
  <module>app-domain</module>
  <module>app-infra</module>
  <module>app-shared</module>
  <module>app-msp/app-management</module>
  <module>app-msp/app-client</module>
</modules>

Then in app-management's pom.xml:
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.company.product</groupId>
  <artifactId>app-infra</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.company.product</groupId>
  <artifactId>app-shared</artifactId>
</dependency>

And in app-infra's pom.xml:
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.company.product</groupId>
  <artifactId>app-domain</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.company.product</groupId>
  <artifactId>app-shared</artifactId>
</dependency>

What I need is to find all modules that one specific module depends on.
For instance I want to list all modules that must be built if I were to build app-msp/app-management, and those would be app-infra, app-shared and app-domain.
Closest thing I found is mvn dependency:tree -pl app-msp/app-management | grep com.company.product, then I would have to manipulate it using some combination of awk or sed along with grep to extract the relevant parts from mvn's output.
I think I could eventually make it work like this, but I am not a fan of this approach, I'd rather only have a maven command to take care of this with no need to resort to some weird, complicated bash commands.

have you checked: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html (-Dincludes=...) instead of grep etc. ?
